# Increase timeout setting for Flask Application

Tags: flask

I have a flask application which I have configured to run on IIS7. I am using web.config file for the required flask configuration and is working great.

In my application I have a section where the user can upload a data file which for processing; per my processing needs this might take more time depending on the file size and for a bigger file the app is timing out.

I need to set the time out to a bigger number. Need help.

here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
   <remove name="Python27_via_FastCGI" />
   <remove name="Python34_via_FastCGI" />
   <add name="Python FastCGI"
      path="*"
      verb="*"
      modules="FastCgiModule"
      scriptProcessor="d:\anaconda3\python.exe|d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"

      resourceType="Unspecified"
      requireAccess="Script" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<appSettings>
  <!-- Required settings -->
  <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="gui.app" />
  <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\PythonProjects\FlaskApp" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can increase the timeout value in flask itself, try the following:

```py
import requests
timeoutSeconds = 5
try:
    res = requests.get(<url>, timeout=timeoutSeconds)
except:
    print("Timeout")
```